# Как сделать многопоточный парсер на python?

Tags: python, парсер

Сделал код

```
import time
import threading
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

#f = open('domains.txt','r')
f = open('temp.txt','r')

def myThread(number):
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        print(threading.currentThread().getName() + ' http://' + line)
        page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
        print(page.status)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        line = f.readline()
    print('Работа потока завершена')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=myThread, args=(i,))
        my_thread.start()
```

temp.txt наподобие такого:

```
00034.ru
00038.ru
0003t.ru
0004.ru
00043.ru
000444.ru
0004444.ru
0005.ru
000500.ru
00054.ru
00055.ru
```

Почему-то вылезают ошибки

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea5149a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "domains.py", line 14, in myThread
    page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0------------------------------------------------bibleonline.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea5149a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "domains.py", line 14, in myThread
    page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0----------------------------------------------------------0.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea5149810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "domains.py", line 14, in myThread
    page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0--------------------------all-domain-lists--zonefiles-io-0.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea5149810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "domains.py", line 14, in myThread
    page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0---------------------------------------------------axelname.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))


Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "domains.py", line 14, in myThread
    page = http.request('GET','http://'+line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0------------------0----0----------0-------0---------------0.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea7c24610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

как быть?

Comment: А там, join`ить не надо случаем?) Почитайте про это.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что все валится из-за ошибки при запросе к сайту.
Попробуйте обернуть запрос в `try except`

```
def myThread(number):
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        try:
            print(threading.currentThread().getName() + ' http://' + line)
            page = http.request('GET', 'http://' + line)
            print(page.status)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            line = f.readline()
        except:
            print('какая-то ошибка')
    print('Работа потока завершена')
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тексту ошибки, ваша проблема в неправильном url:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0--0------------------------------------------------bibleonline.ru%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ea5149a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Хост `host='0--0------------------------------------------------bibleonline.ru%0a'` явно не существует

Comment: такой сайт существовал ранее.

Comment: если проверить с обычными доменами - тоже не работает

Comment: Возможно, но ошибка будет уже другой